# Expression manipulation

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How can one write $\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$ in $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}$ form? In other words, is there something opposite of `Together[]`?

**Edit**

My intend was to write

```
(8380*(x6[t] - x7[t])*(-0.130610 + Sqrt[(x6[t] - x7[t])^2 + (y6[t] - y7[t])^2]))/
   Sqrt[(x6[t] - x7[t])^2 + (y6[t] - y7[t])^2]
```

as

```
8380*(x6[t] - x7[t])*(1 - 0.13061/Sqrt[(x6[t] - x7[t])^2 + (y6[t] - y7[t])^2])
```

Comment: FullSimplify[(a*d + b*c)/(b*d)]

Comment: Also look at `Apart` as the counterpart of `Together`.  For example, `Apart[(a*d + b* c)/(b*d)]`.

Comment: I used both these functions for the expression given in Edit. Neither of them worked.

Comment: `8380*(x6[t]-x7[t])*FullSimplify[(-0.130610 + Sqrt[(x6[t]-x7[t])^2 + (y6[t]-y7[t])^2]) /Sqrt[(x6[t]-x7[t])^2 + (y6[t]-y7[t])^2]]` instantly gives me `8380*(x6[t]-x7[t])*(1-0.13061/Sqrt[(x6[t]-x7[t])^2 + (y6[t]-y7[t])^2])`